# What is a "functional drink" 机能饮料?

Tags: translation

I spotted this at the 物美 supermarket on 四道口 in Beijing.

[image]

<sup>([Imgur version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZwlR.jpg).)</sup>

**Question**: What is a "functional drink" 机能饮料?

The translation seems close to correct:

- [机能](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%BA%E8%83%BD) = "function"
- [饮料](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%A5%AE%E6%96%99) = "drink"

My best guess is that it's a drink suitable for a "function", e.g., a wedding banquet.  But I don't think 机能 has that meaning (it'd be [活动](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B4%BB%E5%8A%A8) = "activity").

Comment: That "function" means *mechanical* or *physiological* function, not an *event* function. Did you get anything on the label at the back? Maybe it gives a story of where the name comes from?

Comment: I didn't look at the back, but I expect it's just plain black.  There were signs like this on other isles, but they made sense [but I forget what they say now].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More commonly known as 機能性飲料, these kinds of "fad" drinks are sold to convey a kind of health benefit, commonly advertised as increasing organ (heart, pancreas, eyes, ...) function. Think herbal or vitamin drinks.

Comment: Ah okay thanks.  I think you've got it (basically it has a function in addition to being a drink)---I found a [机能性饮品 on JD](https://item.jd.hk/53562610748.html) which seems to be that sort of thing.  (I'm out of upvotes for today; I'll have to fix that tomorrow.)  I guess the champagne in the photo is a red herring.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 thank you - you've been very generous to the community with your upvotes (and question/answer reviews) lately!